# Delete several items from a linked list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following list of nodes:

```
MATCH events=(begin)-[:NEXT*]->(end)
WHERE id(begin)=175 AND id(end)=93
RETURN events
```

[image: List of nodes]

And they are labeled as `Pink` or `Gray`.

My question is: **How do I delete pink nodes?**

I have tried the following:

```
MATCH (begin)-[:NEXT*]->(toDelete:Pink)-[:NEXT*]->(end)
WHERE id(begin)=175 AND id(end)=93
WITH toDelete
MATCH (prev)-[r1:NEXT]->(toDelete)-[r2:NEXT]->(next)
CREATE (prev)-[:NEXT]->(next)
DELETE r1,r2,toDelete
```

But I get an error:

> Node[178] is deleted and cannot be used to create a relationship

I more or less understand what's happening but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input data:

```
MATCH (DD:Event) DETACH DELETE DD
MERGE     (a:Event:Gray {name:1})-[:Next]->(b:Event:Pink {name:2})
-[:Next]->(c:Event:Gray {name:3})-[:Next]->(d:Event:Pink {name:4})
-[:Next]->(e:Event:Pink {name:5})-[:Next]->(f:Event:Gray {name:6})
-[:Next]->(g:Event:Gray {name:7})
```

[image]

```
// Get path
MATCH events = (A:Event {name:1})-[:Next*]->(B:Event {name:7})
//
// Separate the gray nodes from pink nodes
WITH nodes(events) as nodes
WITH filter(node in nodes WHERE "Pink" IN LABELS(node)) as pinks,
     filter(node in nodes WHERE "Gray" IN LABELS(node)) as grays
//
// Delete pinks
FOREACH(pink in pinks | DETACH DELETE pink)
//
// Let's go through the gray nodes (without the latter)
WITH grays
UNWIND RANGE(0,size(grays)-2) as i
//
// We find in the way of neighboring pairs between which there is no connection
MATCH (c:Event), (n:Event) 
  WHERE id(c) = id(grays[i]) AND id(n) = id(grays[i+1]) AND NOT (c)-[:Next]->(n)
//
// Create the missing relations
MERGE (c)-[r:Next]->(n)
```

Check results:

[image]